# Geo tragatable website display

Tags: search-engine

i am facing a problem

say i have a website having links as:

```
www.abc.in/india/file.html  //this link is specific to india

www.abc.in/rest_of_world/file.html //this link is for rest of world
```

is there is some way i can tell google to show **india specific links** in search results to **indian users**

like to all indian users see this link : www.abc.in/**india**/file.html    will be shown in search results.

and to rest of world links with www.abc.in/rest_of_world/file.html will be shown.

**Note: GEOIP Targeting is isn't working good for me**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just started using html5 geolocation api's and its very accurate.
http://html5demos.com/geo